# JIT compilation issue in MonoTouch + IKVM project

Tags: java, ios, xamarin.ios, ikvm, aot

I'm porting a Java game to iOS via [ikvm-monotouch](https://github.com/samskivert/ikvm-monotouch) and MonoTouch. I've run into an error that is a bit over my head, although I'm not certain if it's an actual bug in MonoTouch so I'm asking here before hitting the bug database.

I'm getting the JIT compilation error below during a method that reflects on the fields of an object. I've (so far) only seen this error while reflecting on an object that implements `Cloneable`, although I don't know for sure if that's specifically what is triggering this error.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for ikvm.internal.ClassLiteral`1 ---> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'ikvm.internal.ClassLiteral`1<java.lang.Cloneable>:.cctor ()' while running with --aot-only.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Reflection.MonoField.GetValue (System.Object obj) [0x0006a] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoField.cs:124 
   at IKVM.Internal.TypeWrapper.LazyInitClass () [0x00063] in /Users/nathan/projects/ikvm-monotouch-git/runtime/TypeWrapper.cs:1841 
   at IKVM.Internal.TypeWrapper.get_ClassObject () [0x00027] in /Users/nathan/projects/ikvm-monotouch-git/runtime/TypeWrapper.cs:1756 
   at IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Class.getInterfaces (java.lang.Class thisClass) [0x0001c] in /Users/nathan/projects/ikvm-monotouch-git/runtime/openjdk.cs:2556 
   at java.lang.Class.getInterfaces () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields (Set ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields (Set ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at java.lang.Class.getFields (ikvm.internal.CallerID ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Quick link to the ikvm-monotouch TypeWrapper class: https://github.com/samskivert/ikvm-monotouch/blob/master/runtime/TypeWrapper.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line #1841 from TypeWrapper.cs is:

```
clazz = (java.lang.Class)typeof(ikvm.@internal.ClassLiteral<>).
    MakeGenericType(type).GetField("Value").GetValue(null);
```

so it's either related to:

a) `MakeGenericType` in the sense that the AOT compiler does not know, **at compile time**, that it needs to create a `ClassLiteral<Cloneable>`. Since it does not know, it does not compile the required code leading to the `ExecutionEngineException`.

You might be able to workaround this by *hinting* the AOT compiler that the code is needed. E.g. add a, somewhere in your code that will **not** be linked away or optimized out.

```
new ClassLiteral<Cloneable> ();
```

b) `GetField("Value")` in the sense that the (managed) linker could have removed this field. However it should have failed with a `NullReferenceException` (and not inside the .cctor) so I do **not** believe it's a linker issue.

OTOH it's very fast and easy to eliminate this possibility by disabling the linker in your project, rebuild and execute on device (if it starts working then it's a linker issue. You'll be able to workaround this by using the `[Preserve]` attribute on the `Value` field (and re-enable the linker afterward).

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test (b) yet, but if it does turn out to be the issue, I don't know how to apply that attribute (and this is partly my inexperience with C# shining through). ClassLiteral appears to be a runtime-defined dynamic type of some sort (https://github.com/samskivert/ikvm-monotouch/blob/master/runtime/RuntimeHelperTypes.cs#L89). Is it still possible to apply the attribute to that field? I get the impression [Preserve] is a compiler flag?

Comment: IKVM must be doing this at compile time, not runtime, since it would **never** work on iOS which does not allow code generation. Anyway I do not think it's (b) for the reasons mentioned - but trying it (without linking) will confirm this without needed to add the attribute.

Comment: (b) is not the cause. Unfortunately, I am unable to make the hint suggested in (a) a part of my project because ClassLiteral is not available to Java, and we don't want to customize the ikvm-monotouch project specifically for our app. We were probably going to need to get rid of this use of reflection for other reasons eventually anyway though, so I'm just going to work around this problem for now.